# How to save and load the output of seqefsub() in TraMineR

Tags: r, traminer

I have long dataset where I want to experiment with different settings for the seqefsub() function, and depending on the setting, one run can take relatively long. Therefore I want the computer to calculate all the different variations and later evaluate the results, evtl. use them for further processing.

My problem is when I save the results in a file and load them, the structure of the data appears to be broken. As a result I cannot use the TraMineR functions on this data after I load it, hence I need to reproduce all the calculations every single time after closing R.

Saving to the workspace with RStudio (.RData) gives the same error. Saving to binary format gives the same error.

This is how the sequence list looks like in RStudio, before saving:
[image]

And after loading:
[image]

This is the code I used for this example:

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal.tse)
seqe <- seqecreate(actcal.tse[1:100, ])
fsub <- seqefsub(seqe, minSupport = 0.1)
save(fsub, file="fsub.rda")
rm(fsub)
load("fsub.rda")
```

Details of my system:

- x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 14.04 LTE)
- R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
- RStudio Version 0.98.1103
- TraMineR stable version 1.8-9 (Built: 2015-04-22)

Comment: I ran your code in `RStudio` and the line `load("fsub.rda")` crashed `RStudio`. I tried it again with the native `R` console and `R` crashed with a segfault error. When I restarted R and tried to load `fsub.rda` without loading `TraMineR`, `fsub.rda` loaded without a problem, but its structure was different (still a list of 5, but with a different structure and attributes for the list elements). When I then loaded `TraMineR` and typed either `fsub` or `str(fsub)`, R crashed again with a segfault.

Comment: Not sure if the problem described above is a `TraMineR` bug, but thought I'd post in case it might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks for the description. I'm having the exact same problem, including the crashes and everything.

Comment: I checked the `TraMineR` web site and your problem looks like it might be an example of a [known bug](http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1368&group_id=743&atid=2975). The description of this bug also indicates that it's not possible to save event sequences as R data files.

Answer (score 2):

If you [check](http://traminer.unige.ch/doc/seqefsub.html) the value returned from the seqefsub() it is a subseqelist object. This kind object contains other objects listed in the docs as:

> **seqe**:     The list of sequences in which the subsequences were searched (a seqelist event sequence object).
>
> **subseq**: A list of subsequences (a seqelist event sequence object).
>
> **data**: A data frame containing details (support, frequency, ...) about the subsequences

And others. What I did to save the results was to convert the data that I needed in to lists and build a data frame with them before save it.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal.tse)
seqe <- seqecreate(actcal.tse[1:100, ])
fsub <- seqefsub(seqe, minSupport = 0.1)

#Get the data I need only 
#(Explore the other objects to get what you need)====
#Gets the column support from data (which is a data frame)
support <- fsub$data$Support

#subseq is class that cannot be converted to a data frame 
#it stores de subsquences found and I will convert them to strings
sequences <- as.character(fsub$subseq) 

#Builds the data frame
result <- data.frame(sequences, support)

#Save it at root
save(result, file="~/result.rda")

rm(result)

load('~/result.rda')
```

I hope it still helps you.

Comment: I'm not working with TraMineR any more, but this seems to be a workaround. However, as I understand it is still impossible to save and load the `seqelist` and `subseqelist` objects as such. So even after I load `result`, it is still "just" a data frame, which doesn't allow for the same functionality as the two classes mentioned above. Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm writing this from my memory.

Comment: Yes @Balazs , It will be a dataframe. Is there other libraries to work with sequence mining in R?

Comment: I don't know about other libraries, but the reason I'm not using TraMineR is not related to its quality. I just haven't worked on projects that required it since then ;-).